# module.exports give undefined while print module indicates it's not undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs, ecmascript-next

I'm trying to work with a CommonJs module which exports a variable conditionally based on whether `module` and `module.exports` are undefined. The issue I'm currently having is that sometimes when I use `import { something } from 'themodule'` it gives me undefined `something`. While looking into the source code, I found the following export conditions:

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = Prism;
}
```

So I added some logs to the file to see whether the condition is satisfied or not via:

```
console.log('module: ', module, 'module.exports: ', module.exports)
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    console.log('module.exports!')
    module.exports = Prism;
}
```

Which however gives me strange output:

> module:  { exports: [Getter/Setter] } module.exports:  undefined

As you can see, the `module` log seem to indicate it has an `exports` property however when log `module.exports` separately, it says it's undefined. How is this possible ? Can someone help understand why this check is needed and why sometimes `module.exports` can be undefined ? Thanks!

Comment: There’s nothing strange about this output. `console.log({ get exports(){ return undefined; }, set exports(_){} });` logs the same thing. The property is a getter / setter. With `module.exports` you _invoke_ the getter; it returns `undefined`. _Having a property_ and _the property being undefined_ are two separate things. `module.hasOwnProperty("exports")` checks for property existence; `module.exports` checks for truthiness instead. _“why sometimes `module.exports` can be undefined”_ — The same way that `obj.x` is `undefined` in `const obj = { x: undefined };`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Awesome. That makes sense. But in any chance, do you know why  such a check would be needed when exporting a variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mostly-unrelated issues here.

> The issue I'm currently having is that sometimes when I use import { something } from 'themodule' it gives me undefined something

This can occur if you have a circular dependency in your `import` chain. If a.js imports from b.js, and b.js imports from c.js, and c.js imports from a.js - then, for code running at the *top level* of those modules, there's no guarantee that code running at the top level of *other* modules has been executed. While you can experiment and see what's going on, a better approach would be to

- remove the circular dependency, and/or
- have only a single entry point in your code, from which everything else meaningful is called, so that circular dependencies downstream don't cause issues - have your downstream exports be *functions*, without top-level code that depends on other imports.

---

> Which however gives me strange output:
>
> ```
> module: { exports: [Getter/Setter] } module.exports: undefined
> ```

This means that:

- The `exports` property is a getter/setter
- When you invoked the getter, it apparently returned `undefined`. The property exists, but invoking the getter doesn't return anything. Eg

```js
const obj = {
  get prop() {
  }
};

console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('prop'));
console.log(obj.prop);
```

---

> Can someone help understand why this check is needed

The check of

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
```

is simply to check to see if the code is being executed in the CommonJS context, and if it is, it assigns the `Prism` to the exports.

Comment: Great answer. Based on your explanation, it seems my issue is that it's not executing in CommonJS context since if I do `const {something} = require('themodule')`, it works so it shouldn't be circular dependency issue. Do you know how I can check which context I'm currently running at ?